# NodeJS socket.io Broadcast

Tags: node.js, socket.io, server, chat

I'm new to NodeJS, however I have been able to make progress to a certain extent.

As it Is, I have created a nodeJS chat server with socket.io while the client app is a Java desktop application. Every time a user logs out the server emits a broadcast notifying all sockets of the log out event. My fear is that as time goes on, if hundreds of thousand of users are connected it might consume too much of the server resources to continually broadcast to every body each time a user logs out (which could be at a rate of more that one log out per second).

In view, of the above mentioned I'm considering refactoring the code such that each time a user logs out, a database will be queried for the friends of the logged out user so that ONLY the users friends will be notified every time he/she logs out rather that the whole world. But I'm not sure if it's a better way to go about it (considering the database queries per log out), so I am throwing the question to the public.

Which of the stated approaches is a better practice ?

Comment: I suggest you to absolutely restrict the broadcasting of this kind of message to the people in the same chat room.
Sails.js offers a handy way to handle this with subscription.